# Android sort listview with Comparator not working

Tags: java, android, listview, comparator

I have this code in my `onCreate` method to create a custom `listview`:

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, mAllListModel, res);
mFtpDao.open();
final Tupel<String, Boolean> lSort = mFtpDao.loadSort(mCurrentPath);
mFtpDao.close();
adapter.sort(new FtpContentComparator(lSort));

list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

everything is working fine. the listview and the data is displayed as expected. 
But I have problems with my `Comparator`.
My elements are not sorted and the `compare` method is never called.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel> implements
        OnClickListener {
```

Comparator:

```
package de.bc.coreftp.comparator;

import java.util.Comparator;

import de.bc.coreftp.list.ListModel;
import de.beike.consulting.core.ftp.business.Tupel;

public class FtpContentComparator implements Comparator<ListModel> {

    private Tupel<String, Boolean> mSortCriteria;

    public FtpContentComparator(Tupel<String, Boolean> pSortCriteria) {
        mSortCriteria = pSortCriteria;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ListModel arg0, ListModel arg1) {
        String lSortAfter = " Name ";
        if (null != mSortCriteria){
            lSortAfter = mSortCriteria.get1st();
        }

        if (" Name ".equals(lSortAfter)){
            return arg0.getFtpContent().getName().compareTo(arg1.getFtpContent().getName());
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Currently I dont know what's wrong, do you see my mistake?

Best regards

Stefan

Comment: are you using an ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: yes. my CustomAdapter extends from ArrayAdapter

Comment: Could you post `FtpContentComparator`?

Comment: see my edited question. my breakpoint inside compare is never called

Comment: are you providing the dataset to the super constructor of ArrayAdapter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the code you posted everything every thing looks correctly. [ArrayAdapter.sort()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) sorts the dataset you provide. If compare is not called is either because your dataset is empty or you are not providing it to the super constructor, e.g.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel> implements
    OnClickListener {

   public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<ListModel> dataset) {
       super(context, R.id.list, dataset);
   }
```